# UNNEST list of integers in BigQuery query return ```TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable```

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am querying a join of tables in BigQuery for a specific list of ids that are of type `INT64` and I cannot find what to do, as I constantly have th following error

```
TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable
```

My query looks like this:

```
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)

query = """
SELECT t1.*,
t2.*,
t3.*,
t4.* FROM `<project>.<dataset>.<tabel1>` as t1
join `<project>.<dataset>.<tabel2>` as t2
on t1.label = t2.id
join  `<project>.<dataset>.<tabel3>` as t3
on t3.A = t2.A
join `<project>.<dataset>.<tabel4>` as t4
on t4.obj= t2.obj and t4.A = t3.A
where  t1.id in unnest(@list)
"""
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(query_parameters=[
                    bigquery.ArrayQueryParameter("list", "STRING", list),
])
choices= client.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()
```

where my list is of the type:

```
list = [3651056, 3651049, 3640195, 3629411, 3627024,3624939]
```

Now, this method works perfectly whenever the list is of the type:

```
list = ['3651056', '3651049', '3640195', '3629411', '3627024', '3624939']
```

I have tried casting the column I want to pick the list items from before querying but it implies I need to cast the entire table, which contain over 4 billion rows. Not efficient at all.

I would be grateful for any insights on how to solve this.

**EDIT**:

There is one option. Namely to first cast my list to string and then:

```
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)

query = """
SELECT t1.*,
t2.*,
t3.*,
t4.* FROM `<project>.<dataset>.<tabel1>` as t1
join `<project>.<dataset>.<tabel2>` as t2
on t1.label = t2.id
join  `<project>.<dataset>.<tabel3>` as t3
on t3.A = t2.A
join `<project>.<dataset>.<tabel4>` as t4
on t4.obj= t2.obj and t4.A = t3.A
where  cast(t1.id as STRING) in unnest(@list)
"""
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(query_parameters=[
                    bigquery.ArrayQueryParameter("list", "STRING", list),
])
choices= client.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()
```

But is there a more direct way to do this?

Comment: During comparison - both sides needs to be of same data type otherwise BQ will complain. Casting is still best choice for the issue you have with query. But if u want to check if  any side of data can be natively converted to int64 (if u r not expecting any strings etc at all).  That will avoid extra casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PratikPatil mentioned in comments:

During comparison - both sides needs to be of same data type otherwise, **BigQuery** will result to an error.

**Casting** is still best choice for the issue you have with query. But if you want to check if any side of data can be natively converted to `int64` (if you are not expecting any `strings` etc at all). That will avoid extra **casting**.

Posting the answer as *community wiki* as this is the best practice and for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.